# The asp.net Menu hover background color cannot be changed

Tags: asp.net, css

I have menu in asp.net created with Visual Studio 2010. The background color works normally before. One day , I change the background color of a:hover menu, then I cannot change it to another color anymore. I try to change many color or make the background color transparent. However, the CSS seems not work again. I wonder what happened to the asp.net. It works normally before. I try deleted the bin file and also clean the the solution. No one worked.

```
div.menu ul li a:hover
{
background-color: #bfcbd6;
color: #465c71;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: What does the HTML being targeted by this CSS rule look like?

Comment: You have changed something else. What you describe is not possible... if you update the CSS, it will be updated as soon as you refresh your browser, and your server doesn't cache this of course...

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be because of caching, clear your browser cache or try to load the page in private browsing. If you have applied caching to your files, they will be cached, a good thing is to rename the files with version numbers to prevent such problems.